# How to add fade effect in react-table?

Tags: css, reactjs, npm, react-table

While loading, filtering, sorting data, 
how can we add fade effect in react-table?

react-table source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can conditionally add a `className` value, according to `loading, filtering` state, in order to style the table.

**Something like that**:

```
// Conditionally add `--is-filtering` css className
<ReactTable className={isFiltering ? '--is-filtering' : ''} data={data} />

// Basic Fade css styling
.--is-filtering {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: It looks good. However, it will fade whole table (including header, filters), not only data rows.

Comment: You could select and style only the body or any child dom element you want. Something like that: `.is--filtering tbody {}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the boolean `loading` prop provided in **react-table** and also provide a custom `LoadingComponent` prop instead with a CSS fade-in and/or fade-out effect:

#### Basic use example

```
<ReactTable
  data={this.state.data}
  columns={this.state.columns}
  loading={this.state.loading}
  LoadingComponent={YourFadeComponent}
/>
```

Also you can replace any of these components as props if you need a finer approach:

```
  TheadComponent: component,
  TbodyComponent: component,
  TrGroupComponent: component,
  TrComponent: component,
  ThComponent: component,
  TdComponent: component,
  TfootComponent: component,
  ExpanderComponent: component,
  AggregatedComponent: component,
  PivotValueComponent: component,
  PivotComponent: component,
  FilterComponent: component,
  PaginationComponent: component,
  PreviousComponent: undefined,
  NextComponent: undefined,
  LoadingComponent: component,
  NoDataComponent: component,
  ResizerComponent: component
```